# Plotting a table with text-wrapping words

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have to graph a dataframe containing text and the last column contains very long text.
To graph it correctly I need the text once it has passed the vertical grid of the table to be text and new line.

Here is the code that reproduces the problem I want to solve

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dati = {
    'Testo 1': ['Primo testo breve', 'Altro testo breve', 'Un altro breve testo'],
    'Testo 2': ['Testo lungo che può contenere molte parole...', 'Questo è un altro testo lungo con molte parole e frasi.', 'Ancora un esempio di testo lungo.'],
    'Testo 3': ['Testo molto lungo che supera la riga precedente e contiene un gran numero di parole e frasi. Questo testo dovrebbe essere sufficientemente lungo per dimostrare il funzionamento del DataFrame.', 'Questa è unaltra riga di esempio per il testo lungo.', 'Una terza riga per il testo lungo.']
}

# Creazione del DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(dati)

# Creazione della figura e dei sottoplot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
grid = plt.GridSpec(1, 1, hspace=0.5, wspace=0) 

# Aggiunta della tabella al subplot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(grid[0, 0])
table3 = ax1.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, cellLoc='left', loc='center', bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1])
table3.auto_set_font_size(False)
table3.set_fontsize(8)

# Nascondi assi
ax1.axis('off')

# Mostra la tabella
plt.show()
```

Comment: It seems that `matplotlib` is not a good tool for working with text tables, doesn't it? I wonder if `latex` could help, what do you think?